# How to select year in sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

My code:

```
 $results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date = 2014 ORDER BY id DESC', object );
```

The problem is date is stored in this format: 2014-01-01
So how do I select just the year ( I don't care about month and day for the time being ).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `year()` function:

```
WHERE year(date) = 2014
```

or use explicit comparisons:

```
WHERE (date >= '2014-01-01' and date < '2015-01-01')
```

The latter is better because it can make use of an index on the `date` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE year(`date`)='2014' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all rows where the year of a date column (called date_col) is equal to 2014 use the [year function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE Year(`date_col`) = '2014';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select year for get posts with query_posts(); parameter is **year**. Example: query_posts("year=2014"); This is not full question for you, only alternative..